# Событие в текущий момент времени (по расписанию)

Tags: mysql

Существует таблица с колонкой времени, как настроить событие на  эту колонку когда указанное в ней время равно now. Т.е. когда время в колонке равно текущему запускать событие

Comment: Нет, так не делается... Вам надо на сервере настроить событие, которое будет проверять, наступило ли время...

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что событие будет пробегать по колонке например раз в минуту и проверять наступило ли время или нет?

Comment: @VladimirLenkov Да, правильно. Хотя я бы пожалй в постоянно запущенном скрипте запоминал ближайшее время и спал до его настпуления. Это если есть возможность сообщить снаружи скрипту, что произошли изменения и базу надо перечитать

Comment: @cyadvert не покажешь пример, мне непонятно как обращаться ко всем значениям в столбце, для сравнения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам лучше сделать иначе. Лучше создать MySQL EVENT и уже в нем проверять, есть ли какие-то записи с наступившей датой.

Чтобы найти нужные записи надо сделать типа такого:
`SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [колонка_времени] BETWEEN DATEADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 MINUTE) AND NOW();`

Я не знаю, что Вы хотите делать с записями, `UPDATE` или `SELECT`, а потом пролистывать... главное - `WHERE` statement: вернет Вам все записи, где значение колонки [колонка времени] между 5 минут назад и сейчас.

MySQL событие можно создать используя синтакс `CREATE EVENT`
Что-то типа такого:

```
CREATE  EVENT [db_name].[event_name]
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
DO
    BEGIN
        [sql_statements]
    END;
```